# How to run SSIS package by loading different package configuration files?

Tags: sql, ssis

In SSIS 2008, is it possible to create multiple Configuration Manager configurations from separate `dtsconfig` files?

If so, I am not sure where to create the connection. The reason being is that we have a test cluster and a live cluster. I would like to be able to select `development` or `production` configurations in order to run on separate clusters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the dtsconfig file path in the dtexec arguments using `/CONFIGFILE "Drive:\Path\To\Your\Config.dtsConfig"`

For instance :

```
dtexec /FILE "C:\Ssis\MyPackage.dtsx" /CONFIGFILE "C:\Ssis\MyPackage.dtsConfig"
```